# get the redirected url

Tags: python, python-requests

Hey i have a problem with getting the redirect url from my "base" url

heres my code:

i found a lot of tipps in the internet but nothing really works. always get my "base" url but it should output the url it gets redirected to.

does someone have any idea?

```
url = apiurl.de/apiexample'
        servers = session.get(url, headers=headers).result().json()['results']
        for server in servers:
            server_id = server['id']
            
            invite_url = f'apiurl.com/api'

            user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
            
            s = requests.Session()
            s.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent
            r = s.get(invite_url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)

            print(f'[redirected url]: {r.url}')
```

[image]

Comment: Confused, the base url is what string in this context?

Comment: im sorry, the base url is "invite_url"

Comment: Hopefully `r.history` helps

Comment: r.history delivers me []